# Error while making an installer with installshield

Tags: vb.net, matlab, installshield

I'm using installshield LE to make an installer. Here's what I included in the **Application Files**
[image]

But after installing the program and running it, when I clicked the **Nitrogen** or **Disease** button I got this error:
[image]

By the way, every time I click **Nitrogen** or **Disease** button, I'm calling for the DLL files that I generated using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is trying to load an assembly and either that assembly or one of it's dependencies is missing.  InstallShield has failed to automagically author your installer for you.   Personally I believe in dependency analysis and explicit installation authoring so I wouldn't try to use the big easy button feature myself.